# mysql-workbench: Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module

Tags: python, bash, mysql-workbench, dependencias

Trato de ejecutar *MySQL Workbench 8.0.25*. El script `mysql-workbench` ejecuta:

```
catchsegv /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
```

Error:

```sh
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/_collections_abc.py", line 12, in <module>
    GenericAlias = type(list[int])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Registro:

```sh
method return time=1623961166.370118 sender=:1.436 -> destination=:1.764 serial=77 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<!-- GDBus 2.64.3 -->
<node>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
    <method name="Get">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetAll">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="properties" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Set">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="PropertiesChanged">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="changed_properties"/>
      <arg type="as" name="invalidated_properties"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
    <method name="Introspect">
      <arg type="s" name="xml_data" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer">
    <method name="Ping"/>
    <method name="GetMachineId">
      <arg type="s" name="machine_uuid" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.gnome.keyring.InternalUnsupportedGuiltRiddenInterface">
    <method name="ChangeWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="original" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ChangeWithPrompt">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="CreateWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="attributes" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="UnlockWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service">
    <method name="OpenSession">
      <arg type="s" name="algorithm" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="input" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="output" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="result" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="CreateCollection">
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="properties" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="alias" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SearchItems">
      <arg type="a{ss}" name="attributes" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="unlocked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="locked" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Unlock">
      <arg type="ao" name="objects" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="unlocked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Lock">
      <arg type="ao" name="objects" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="locked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="Prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="LockService"/>
    <method name="ChangeLock">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetSecrets">
      <arg type="ao" name="items" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="session" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="a{o(oayays)}" name="secrets" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ReadAlias">
      <arg type="s" name="name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetAlias">
      <arg type="s" name="name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="CollectionCreated">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="CollectionDeleted">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="CollectionChanged">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <property type="ao" name="Collections" access="read"/>
  </interface>
  <node name="collection"/>
</node>
"
Found /usr/lib/libproj.so.22
catchsegv /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin --log-level debug3 --log-to-stderr

(process:22975): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:19:37.098: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Logger set to level 'debug3'. '1111111'
17:19:38 [INF][      WBContext]: Logger set to level 'debug3'
17:19:38 [DB2][ mforms backend]: Initializing mforms factory
17:19:38 [DB1][      WBContext]: Creating WBContext
17:19:38 [INF][   WBContext UI]: Initializing workbench context UI with these values:
    base dir: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    plugin path: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins
    struct path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt
    module path: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules
    library path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries
    user data dir: /root/.mysql/workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No
17:19:38 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
17:19:38 [DB1][  GRTDispatcher]: starting worker thread
17:19:38 [DB1][  GRTDispatcher]: worker thread running
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.Management, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder GrtObjectCreating metaclass db.mgmt.Rdbms, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.PrivilegeMapping, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.Driver, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.PythonDBAPIDriver, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.DriverParameter, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.Connection, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.SSHConnection, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.SSHFile, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.ServerInstance, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mgmt.SyncProfile, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mgmt.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mssql.Catalog, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.CatalogCreating metaclass db.mssql.Schema, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.SchemaCreating metaclass db.mssql.Table, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.TableCreating metaclass db.mssql.Column, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.ColumnCreating metaclass db.mssql.SimpleDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.SimpleDatatypeCreating metaclass db.mssql.UserDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.UserDatatypeCreating metaclass db.mssql.StructuredDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.StructuredDatatypeCreating metaclass db.mssql.Index, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.IndexCreating metaclass db.mssql.IndexColumn, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.IndexColumnCreating metaclass db.mssql.ForeignKey, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.ForeignKeyCreating metaclass db.mssql.Trigger, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.TriggerCreating metaclass db.mssql.View, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.ViewCreating metaclass db.mssql.RoutineGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.RoutineGroupCreating metaclass db.mssql.Routine, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.RoutineCreating metaclass db.mssql.Synonym, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.SynonymCreating metaclass db.mssql.Sequence, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mssql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder db.SequenceCreating metaclass app.Application, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Document, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Info, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.DocumentInfo, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Options, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Starters, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Starter, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Registry, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PaperType, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PageSettings, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.CustomDataField, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.CommandItem, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.MenuItem, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.ShortcutItem, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Toolbar, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.ToolbarItem, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PluginGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.Plugin, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.DocumentPlugin, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PluginInputDefinition, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PluginSelectionInput, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PluginFileInput, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass app.PluginObjectInput, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.app.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.Editor, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.QueryBuffer, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.QueryEditor, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.ResultPanel, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.Resultset, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.EditableResultset, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.ResultsetColumn, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.query.LiveDBObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.query.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.DatabaseObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder GrtNamedObjectCreating metaclass db.DatabaseDdlObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.Role, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.RolePrivilege, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.User, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.LogFileGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.Tablespace, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.ServerLink, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.DatatypeGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.CheckConstraint, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.Event, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.CharacterSet, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.Script, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder GrtStoredNoteCreating metaclass db.DatabaseSync, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.DatabaseSyncObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass meta.Tag, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.meta.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass meta.TaggedObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.meta.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.physical.Diagram, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder model.DiagramCreating metaclass workbench.physical.Layer, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder model.LayerCreating metaclass workbench.physical.Model, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder model.ModelCreating metaclass workbench.physical.TableFigure, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder model.FigureCreating metaclass workbench.physical.ViewFigure, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.physical.RoutineGroupFigure, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.physical.Connection, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.physical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder model.ConnectionCreating metaclass workbench.model.NoteFigure, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.model.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.model.ImageFigure, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.model.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.logical.Model, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.logical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.logical.Diagram, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.logical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.logical.Entity, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.logical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.logical.Relationship, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.logical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.logical.Connection, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.logical.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass ui.ModelPanel, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.ui.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass placeholder TransientObjectCreating metaclass ui.ObjectEditor, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.ui.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass ui.db.ConnectPanel, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.ui.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.model.reporting.TemplateInfo, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.model.reporting.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.model.reporting.TemplateStyleInfo, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.model.reporting.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass GrtLogObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass GrtLogEntry, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass GrtMessage, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass GrtVersion, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass grt.PyObject, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.wrapper.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass mforms.ObjectReference, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.wrapper.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass parser.ContextReference, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.wrapper.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass model.Object, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.model.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass model.Group, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.model.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass model.Marker, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.model.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Catalog, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Schema, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.LogFileGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Tablespace, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.ServerLink, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.PartitionDefinition, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Table, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Column, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.SimpleDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.StructuredDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Index, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.IndexColumn, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.ForeignKey, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Trigger, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Event, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.View, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.RoutineGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Routine, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.RoutineParam, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Synonym, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.Sequence, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.StorageEngineOption, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.mysql.StorageEngine, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.mysql.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Object, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Catalog, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Schema, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Entity, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Attribute, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.DatatypeGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Datatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass eer.Relationship, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.eer.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.Workbench, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.xml
17:19:38 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.Document, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass workbench.OverviewPanel, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.workbench.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.migration.Migration, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.migration.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.migration.DBPreferences, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.migration.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.migration.DatatypeMapping, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.migration.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.migration.MigrationParameter, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.migration.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Catalog, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Schema, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Table, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Column, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.SimpleDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.StructuredDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.UserDatatype, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Index, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.IndexColumn, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.ForeignKey, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Trigger, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.View, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.RoutineGroup, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Routine, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Synonym, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
17:19:39 [DB3][            grt]: Creating metaclass db.sybase.Sequence, from source: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt/structs.db.sybase.xml
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/_collections_abc.py", line 12, in <module>
    GenericAlias = type(list[int])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Edité `mysql-workbench`:

```
export PYTHONHOME="/usr/lib64/python3.9"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib64/python3.9"
```

¿Cómo se repara este error?

Comment: El `TypeError` lo está dando una versión de python que no entiende las _anotaciones de tipos_. Aunque cambies el `PYTHONPATH`, el workbench se debe estar ejecutando con la versión de python2 del sistema. Prueba a forzar la ejecución con `python3 /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes El problema es que es un binario... `python3 /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
  File "/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin", line 1
    ELF
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: Mirando varios bugs de mysql-workbench, el binario tiene un python 2.7 empotrado con PYTHONPATH fijo. Parece que no se está desarrollando desde hace años, siendo incompatible con la configuración actual del python 3.9 de tu sistema. Se puede hacer algún _workaround_, pero me faltaría información. Ejecuta el workbench en una cónsola con las siguientes opciones y añade la salida a la pregunta: `MySQLWorkbench --log-level debug3 --log-to-stderr`

Comment: También asegúrate que estás usando la última versión MySQL Workbench 8.0.25

Comment: @ChemaCortes Ya edité la pregunta con el `log`.

Comment: No es que dé mucha información. Voy a intentar darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysql-workbench** tiene empotrado un python2. Como todo python, lo primero que intenta hacer al iniciarse es importar el módulo [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) para ajustar las rutas donde buscar los módulos.

En tu sistema, la localización del módulo `site` está determinada por la variable de entorno [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Como tienes por defecto la versión de python 3.9, esta variable apunta a `/usr/lib64/python3.9`, de donde pilla el módulo `site`.

En resumen, el python2 empotrado en mysql-workbench intenta importar el módulo `site` de python3, fallando con una *anotación de tipos* que se introdujo para python 3.9 [¹](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Como solución más simple que se me ocurre sería eliminar la variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH` antes de ejecutar mysql-workbench para que no use módulos fuera de los que tiene empotrados:

```sh
$ export PYTHONPATH=''; mysql-workbench
```

Un modo alternativo:

```sh
$ env -u PYTHONPATH mysql-workbench
```

Comment: Con las librerías del 2.7 no funciona, pero logré arrancarlo cambiando a Python 3.5: `export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib64/python3.5"`... Da error al iniciar `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'
` pero a pesar de este error funciona, me cargó la interfaz.

Comment: Bueno, no duró mucho, hice click en _About Workbench_ y se me cerró. Dio un error muy largo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSUGI.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0vnF.png

Comment: Por lo demás está funcionando bien, ya lo abrí otra vez, el problema era solo con el _About Workbench_.

Comment: Ahora veo que tiene otros problemas, no puede abrir bases de datos guardadas `(mysql-workbench-bin:28000): glibmm-ERROR **: 21:04:02.848: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid` y tampoco funciona el autoguardado cada tantos minutos. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkA3.png

Comment: No me fiaría mucho para su uso en producción. Quizás te interese probar con [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io)

Comment: Me funciona bien el DBeaver, el único inconveniente es que está hecho en Java, como consecuencia consume más memoria, pero la cantidad de errores está muy reducida. Gracias, no lo conocía.